# How can I overcome (or what leads to) empty Azure Automation Module blades?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation, powershell-module

[image]

I've seen this a handful of times and it's unclear why it is the case. It's not simple a matter of having not loaded yet - the Delete button, for instance, is inactive until the blade fully loads (and the little horizontal progress indicator at the top of the blade works as usual).

It is persistent across browsers/portal sessions, users, etc.

In the runbook editor(s), the Module appears to be loaded and expandable to see its members, but as this module was recently updated, I have no way of knowing if it is actually updated or if that's just the listing of the previous module. If something is so wonky with the 'provisioning' or 'importing' or 'extracting' that the portal can't even render the blade for the module, I have little faith that everything is A-OK under the covers.

Even worse, I have no way of interrogating any output from the operations in order to remediate any potential problems - as far as my code (or portal) is concerned, the module uploaded, imported, and extracted successfully, even though it didn't, actually.

I've noticed that some system-level jobs must be responsible for these imports/extractions, because the Job Statistics Monitoring Tile on the Automation Account ticks up the count when a module is being imported, yet these phantom Jobs don't actually show up in the Jobs list (and obviously, nor do the runbooks underpinning them).

Comment: Can you share one of the modules that you are trying to import?  Also, are you importing the module programmatically or in the UX?  What browsers are you seeing this behavior in (I know that you mentioned a number of browsers)?

Comment: Thanks Beth. I will put together a vanilla module (I already want to do this for the workflow .ps1 not importing issue), hopefully by EOW. That said, there was nothing that seemed to indicate the contents of the module in particular was the cause; I can delete & re-import the same module fine.

Comment: These were all imported via the UI, in either Edge or Chrome. Once I saw this problem in loading, in order to verify it wasn't just the portal's browser cache/state acting funky, I tried it from IE and new sessions of Chrome/Edge. In this same browser session where it does _not_ load, the _other_ modules' blade _do_ load. I'm working _toward_ automating the deployments (most likely via PS/SDK first, then ARM templates).

Comment: Thanks.  Having something to test with will make it easier for us to solve this issue. I've opened a bug to track this for the Automation team in the meantime.

Comment: I think it may have to do with importing too fast, after either the previous one finished importing, or was deleted.

Comment: Thanks Joe.  You were using this module when you saw this, right? https://github.com/JoeBrockhaus/AzureAutomationVsoGitSync

Comment: @ElizabethCooper I've seen it with multiple Modules, including that one. I never tried real hard to reproduce it, but I've seen it a handful or times in the process of updating modules during POC work.